# Why does my graphics card have glitches and low performance with the latest nouveau driver in debian?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, nouveau, graphic-card

I have a graphics card of the NVE4 type as listed [here](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/). According to the list and this [feature matrix](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/) it should be compatible with the FOSS nouveau driver for nvidea graphics cards.

I have xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 1.0.16-1 installed, no proprietary graphics driver installed and the display did work so the driver must have been loaded.

I have three problems related to the graphics card and/or the driver:

- it does have glitches where it shortly shows green space across the screen
- when running an emulator the graphics performance seems to be at least as bad as with CPU-only
- when testing with the emulator my computer often froze so that I had to force-reboot by holding the power button

It might be relevant that [I had display problems with KDE Plasma after upgrading from Debian 9 to 10 which went away after putting the graphics card (which I removed before upgrading) back in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534587/problems-with-kde-plasma-after-upgrading-to-debian-10-too-bright-and-glowy-fav/582413).

Comment: By 'emulator', you mean a virtual machine? As I understand it, in general, a GPU won't be available in a VM guest, unless you use [PCI passthrough](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU/Guest_graphics_acceleration), which not all hardware combinations (i.e. CPU/mainboard) support. I'm not sure about the glitches though.

Comment: No, I meant a game console emulator (dolphin).

Comment: Based on my experience with virtual machines, I would be surprised if it was very straightforward to passthrough the GPU to an emulator like that, without some sort of hardware-level support like PCI passthrough. An emulator is basically a virtual machine, after all.

Comment: Well, the dolphin emulator is made for this (GPU-intensive games) and I went through all its graphics settings.